# I cant access the acessor method of another class? java

Tags: java

when I try to access the method of another class, it gives me an error that non-static method can't be accessed from static method but none of my methods are static.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class creatureClassDriverRathtarsGame
   {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   creatureClass player = new creatureClass("name", 14,new locationClass(0, 0, 0));
   ArrayList <locationClass> locationRathTars = new <locationClass> ArrayList(5);
   for(locationClass r: locationRathTars)
   {
       int randomRow = (Math.random() * ((locationClass.getMaxRow()) + 1));
       int randomCol = (Math.random() * ((locationClass.getMaxCol()) + 1));
       creatureClass rathtars = new creatureClass("rathtars",0, new locationClass(randomRow, randomCol, 0));
   }
```

and the acessor method that is being called is

```
   public int getMaxRow()
{
    return maxrow;
}
public int getMaxCol()
{
    return maxcol;
}
```

Comment: Please post an actual [mcve]. As it stands, I'm assuming your class is called `locationClass` and you are in fact calling methods from it statically.

Comment: Following basic java code conventions would have pointed out the problem. Class names must start with a capital letter. instance (object) of a class should have a camel-cased name.

Comment: You are calling locationClass.getMaxRow() when you want to be calling r.getMaxRow()

Answer (score 0):

at first you must have the basic knowledge for java classes and objects and the difference between static and non-static members

to call a method using class name it must be static

so your acessor method should look like the blew

```
public static int getMaxRow()
{
   return maxrow;
}
public static int getMaxCol()
{
   return maxcol;
}
```

hope this is useful